# $routeParams not returning Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that I'm trying to access the parameters on using $routeParams but when I check the value with console.log a reference to lodash is being made.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('card-info.controller', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('CardInfoController', CardInfoController);

  CardInfoController.$inject = [
    'fetchCard',
    'fetchSet',
    '_',
    '$routeParams',
    '$filter',
    '$location'
  ];

  function CardInfoController (fetchCard, _, $routeParams, $filter, $location) {
    var vm = this;
    var id = $routeParams.id;

    fetchCard.getCardInfo(id).then(function(d) {
      displayCard(d);
    });

  ...

  }
)}()
```

Here is a link to the [controller](https://github.com/parrott-kevin/mtg-stats/blob/master/public/app/components/card-info/card-info.controller.js). The router event is firing and the URL is changing properly it just seems like there is something wrong within my injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wrong offset between your injected value and the name of it

You injected `fetchSet` but you did not use it in the function signature

This

```
function CardInfoController (fetchCard, _, $routeParams, $filter, $location) {
```

Should be

```
function CardInfoController (fetchCard, fetchSet, _, $routeParams, $filter, $location) {
```

And the cosmic order of the great signature is restored

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it. Is there an easy way to avoid this in the future of do I just need to be more diligent in my watching what injections are being done?

Comment: Unit testing is designed to avoid this, I suggest you have a look at karma and jasmine which are good unit tests tools (at least were, when I used to develop on a daily basis with angularjs, I might be outdated)

Answer (score 1):

`$routeParams` is a service of the `ngRoute` module, you have to add it to your module declaration:

```
 angular
  .module('card-info.controller', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute'])
  .controller('CardInfoController', CardInfoController);
```

Source: [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)